# How to make a SearchView only look for coincidences if a key/button is pressed, not on if the text changes

Tags: android, searchview

I need to add a search functionality to my app.

All the queries are going to be made upon a table (SQLite table) that might have 6 or 7 thousand records and I don't think it would be good idea to perform searches on this table for every single character the user enters. For that reason I only want to look for coincidences when the user has done typing and he/she presses a find button (which would be great it was only enabled if the user entered a minimum number of characters)

Do you know how this can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried SearchViewsetOn* listeners?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setSubmitButtonEnabled(true) ?